# DDD Request & Activity Tracking

Tags: api, request, command, domain-driven-design

I have a question about tracking activity and where it belongs.

With a lot of my domain commands, you also might want to track the activity and modifications made by users to a particular context or object.

For example:
lets say we have a items domain/context where we can create and edit items. Users are going to make requests to the api to do this. We might want to track who created an item and an modifications made to it.

In a typical CRUD model, you'd probably find the created by field in the domain object/table

Something doesn't feel right when using DDD to have the activity in the domain object. The activity log feels like a general service that would cross many boundaries? Is it right to have the activity log of who changed what in the domain object. It would feel quite clean and focused without it. The activity logging seems specific to the applications case, not the domain?

So:
Should the activity tracking be in the domain object?
If it shouldn't how do you go about handling this in one command/request. I keep hearing people saying about you should only touch 1 boundary in a command/request.

Answer (score 1):

I would think of this activity log as any other piece of data. You would put it together with the business logic around it. Why do you need this information in the first place? Is your `items context` going to implement business logic that needs the activity log? If not, then I'd say it doesn't belong in that context.

If what you are trying to achieve with this log is some data analysis that needs the activity from several contexts, then I would say publish events from your business operations (every time a user does something with one of the contexts) and have your activity tracking context listen to them and store the activity in a way that serves this purpose.

If, instead, your items context needs to apply some sort of logic, based on the past activity, then keep it in that context in a format that allows you to implement this business logic.

It's also possible that you actually need both. Some context might just publish the events and not store the activity, while others will publish the events and also track the activity for their own internal needs.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, yes this makes sense. My activity log is just more of a tracker to show opposed to having any relevance to the item context.
So, because the item context doesn't need it for logic, it is a separate context. My only confusion still though is, if this activity tracker listed to events, how does it get information like who performed the action? e.g. track who created an item
This information is part of the api call but it wouldnt be in the item's event that is published, beacuse it might not be part of its logic.

Comment: so do i have this information part of all context's apis/in an api gateway? e.g. call a command on the item service to create an item and if successful, then call the activity service to create a activity log regarding this item and the api caller?
To put it simpler, my issue is how do you get information that would go into the acvitiy log, if it is not part of the events you trying to track activity for? e.g. the api caller/who created it

Comment: I guess you can solve this in many ways, but the way I normally do it is that for every API call I create a RequestContext, which contains information about the request, which always contains the UserId. This context is propagated everywhere, so if that request ends up into a Command that gets handled in a microservice and then this microservice publishes an event, the context will be in the event, so the receiver of the event will have access to the information about the user who initiated the operation. But you could simply pass the UserId in all your operations and always add it to the

Comment: events. After all, who did a business operation is a very relevant field, so adding it to all events makes sense.